# Duvida de iniciante no javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma dúvida e código segue abaixo:

```js
var j = 1928182;

while (j > 50) {
    console.log(j);
    j /= 5;
}
```

Como o código diz, enquanto `j` for maior que 50, ele vai dividir por 5, certo? Por que se colocar o `console.log` antes da condição de `j` ser dividido por 5, ele aparece da mesma forma o resultado? Com tudo nessa linguagem é assim?

Comment: @rd_1999 por ser uma linguagem interpretada e sequencial. Nesse seu console.log(), o resultado de saída seria o valor (número) que está sendo dividido por 50.

Comment: é que por exemplo, CSS utiliza tipo em formato de cascata certo? to perguntando que se nao precisa meio que "por uma ordem", pq ali eu dei o comando de aparecer no console, antes de o J dividir por 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi a sua duvida, `while` irá rodar várias vezes, enquanto o `j` for MAIOR que 50, conforme for dividindo esse numero vai decrescendo, quando ficar igual ou menor que 50 o `while` vai parar.

O `console.log` é para saber qual o valor atual do `j` a cada ciclo do `while`, por exemplo, sem o `while` você teria algo como:

```js
j = 1928182;
console.log(j);
j /= 5;
console.log(j);
j /= 5;
console.log(j);
j /= 5;
console.log(j);
j /= 5;
console.log(j);
j /= 5;
console.log(j);
j /= 5;
console.log(j);
j /= 5;
console.log(j);
j /= 5;
```

Seria semelhante a fazer isto:

```js
j = 1928182;

while (j > 50) {
    console.log(j);
    j /= 5;
}
```

Foram exibidos os mesmos resultados, ou seja o `console.log` é para saber qual valor será divido, provavelmente para analisar o processo passo a passo.

Lembrando que o `console.log` é uma função para ser usado com o as ferramentas:

- Chrome DevTools
- Microsoft developer tools
- Firefox Developer Tools

e outras semelhantes (como console de motores javascript independetes de browsers)